# Binary operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let binary operation $ \circ $ on set $X$ be function $\circ : X \times X \rightarrow X$.

Binary operation on set X is :

- unitary if for some element $1 \in X$ and any $x \in X$ we've got $(1 \circ x) = x = (x \circ 1)$
- alternate if for any $x,y \in X$ we've got $x \circ y = y \circ x$.

Show that:

1) $x \circ (y \circ x) = y \implies (x \circ y) \circ x = y$

2) Let $\circ$ and $\star$ be binary operation on $X$. $\circ$ and $\star$ are unitary and for any $a,b,c,d \in X$ we've got $(a \circ b) \star (c \circ d) = (a \star c) \circ (b \star d)$. Show that $\star$ and $\circ$ are alternate and identical.

Thanks for help.

Comment: FYI, "alternate" is more commonly called "commutative" or "abelian".

Comment: Thanks :D I used google translate :)

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an explicit, fully-defined example showing that (1) is false in general.

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
\circ&a&b\\ \hline
a&b&b\\
b&a&b
\end{array}$$

Then

$$a\circ(b\circ a)=a\circ a=b\;,$$

but

$$(a\circ b)\circ a=b\circ a=a\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

2) Let $a=c=1$ then,
$$b\star c=c \circ b \qquad(1)$$
Then you can use this identity (1) to change order as
$$(b \star a) \star (d \star c) = (b \star d) \star (a \star c).$$
Then let $b=c=1$ so,
$$ a \star d = d \star a,$$
 which implies that $\star$ is alternative. You can prove for $\circ$ similarly. Now that $\star$ is alternative we can rewrite (1) as
$$c\star b=c \circ b,$$which proves that $\star$ and $\circ$ are identical.

Comment: Be careful - there might be different $1$ elements for $\star$ and $\circ$."

Comment: Which $1$ do you mean when you set $a=c=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is false.  Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$

We can have $1 \circ (2 \circ 1) = 2$ with $2 \circ 1 = 3$, but $(1 \circ 2) \circ 1 = 5$ with $1 \circ 2 = 5$.

Comment: How do you know the values of the result of operating by $\circ$?

Comment: @MLT The user didn't mention anything about the binary operation.  I'm defining it however I want.

Comment: @MLT You cannot prove this implication without additional assumptions on $\circ$.  I have defined a binary operation that doesn't satisfy it.

Comment: Well, you haven't defined it, but you started defining it. :)